# How do I solve the cereal box problem when I want to find the median, not the mean?

Tags: probability

The [cereal box problem](http://mste.illinois.edu/reese/cereal/) is the problem of finding the mean number of cereal boxes that I have to purchase in order to receive each prize at least once, if there are $N$ different prizes, and each box has a random prize.

If we set $N = 6$, the solution for the traditional problem is given by $$6/6+6/5+6/4+6/3+6/2+6/1 = 14.7$$

The pattern is pretty straight-forward.

But what if I wanted to find the *median* number of boxes that I needed to purchase?  This definitely transforms the problem into something completely different.  I haven't been able to make much progress on it yet.

However, I remember that several years ago, when I was in sixth grade, I had made an attempt to solve this very same problem. Here is the solution that I came up with:
$$R \approx 1 +\frac{\log{N}}{\log{(N)}-\log{(N-1)}}$$

Since many years have transpired since I was in sixth grade, I honestly have no clue how I derived that formula, and I don't know how to reproduce it.  I also highly doubt that it is correct, as I now know a lot more about the geometric probability distribution.

So, what is the *proper* formula for the median?

Comment: The problem is more commonly known as the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).